# Where can I find something similar to a fluorescent tube, with only one end for electrical contact

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I want to redo the floor light in the front patio. My idea is to create a few light rods coming out of the floor and pointing toward the ceiling. For this purpose, it would be nice if the anode and the cathode could be close instead of spread at each extremities. It can be LED or even regular light, I just can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I guess I'm not using the right words... This sketch might help you.

[image: A little sketch]

Comment: Can you say [Tesla coil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwq2gj1eER8)?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "light saber".

Comment: End-lit lucite rods

Answer (score 1):

I would use LED replacement bulbs for Fluorescent tubes. With LED tubes there are some that are designed to work without removing the ballast and some that need to have the ballast removed.

The ones that need the ballast removed and also require changing the sockets are the ones you want. Standard fluorescent tube fixtures come with shunted sockets where both pins are connected. Non-shunted means each pin can be wired separately. The LED tubes I've used that required ballast removal and changing the socket have come with non-shunted sockets but you can also purchase them separately.

You can build a base and mount the sockets in it and have some sort of friction device to hold the tubes. There are obvious concerns about safety with having electric wires outdoors in a diy fixture but I'll leave that to other more qualified members to address.

I have some diagrams and pictures on [how to rewire a shoplight for LED tubes](http://tombuildsstuff.blogspot.com/2015/05/hyperikon-ballast-compatible-review.html) which you may find useful.

The only issue is that all the LED tubes I've seen only have light coming out on one side. Not sure if that fits in to your plans but I think it's safer than having fragile glass in such a vulnerable location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a "Maker", you could use low-voltge LED strips which have rows of LEDs on a flexible strip about 3/8” wide and backed with sticky-tape. They only emit about 140-180 degrees, but you could stick them to both sides of a strip of aluminum or fiberboard shoved up inside a transparent or translucent (fogged) pipe. That would give near 360 degree light coverage.

The LED strips come in any color you want, as long as it's not black.  Typically less than ten bucks for a 16-foot strip.  (Though many outfits will brazenly charge $100 for the same thing).

They also make RGB variants which allow you to make the strip any color you want and dynamically change it on the fly.  Imagine your tube slowly turning from green to orange, then suddenly to yellow, with each tube being a different color.

They also make RGB strips which are individually addressible, that is, you can command any particular LED to be any color. Imagine patterns of light racing up and down each tube.  You're getting into more cost and some actual programming skills but the sky's the limit as far as very complex animated patterns.